# Java Android - Show more element in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, onscroll

i use setOnScrollListener that show other element.

```
lvMain.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if(firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount) {
                        boxAdapter.count += visibleItemCount;
                        boxAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    else
                    {}
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

        });
```

By default, the list gets only 10 elements.

```
  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    //return objects.size();
      return 10;
  }
```

Everything is loaded when I scroll, but when I reach the end of the application is closed. What is the reason?

LogCat:

```
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068): Process: com.example.warapp, PID: 31068
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 100, size is 100
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at com.example.warapp.BoxAdapter.getItem(BoxAdapter.java:49)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at com.example.warapp.BoxAdapter.getView(BoxAdapter.java:67)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2240)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:655)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5136)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4247)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-28 18:27:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(31068):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

BaseAdapter:

```
public class BoxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
      Context ctx;
      LayoutInflater lInflater;
      ArrayList<ItemInfo> objects;
      String name;
      int count = 10;

      BoxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemInfo> products) {
        ctx = context;
        objects = products;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      }



      // кол-во элементов
      @Override
      public int getCount() {
        //return objects.size();
          return count;
      }

      // элемент по позиции
      @Override
      public ItemInfo getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
      }

      // id по позиции
      @Override
      public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
      }


      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
          view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        }

        ItemInfo p = getItem(position);

        if (p.username.contains("null"))
        {
            name = "Автор: Неизвестен";
        }
        else
        {
           name = "Автор: " + p.username;
        }

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(name);
        return view;
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I improved your adapter and added a `loadAdditionalItems()` method. So when you reach the bottom of your list view just call this:

```
adapter.loadAdditionalItems();
```

Here is the adapter:

```
public class BoxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final Context context;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final ArrayList<ItemInfo> itemInfos;

    private final int loadCount = 10;

    private int count = 10;
    private String name;

    BoxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemInfo> products) {
        this.context = context;
        this.itemInfos = products;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemInfo getItem(int position) {
        return itemInfos.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void loadAdditionalItems() {
        this.count += this.loadCount;
        if (this.count > this.itemInfos.size()) {
            this.count = this.itemInfos.size();
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        }

        // You should implement the ViewHolder pattern, google for it.

        ItemInfo p = getItem(position);

        if (p.username.contains("null")) {
            name = "Автор: Неизвестен";
        } else {
            name = "Автор: " + p.username;
        }

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(name);
        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: i have 100 elements, and i want show 10, and when the user reaches the end, I want to get another 10 and so on until 100

Comment: I suspected you wanted to do something like that. Anyway have you already tried my suggestion? Is it working? If not, please post more code. Especially from your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [Android-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) that you can use to achieve what you are trying to do.

[Here](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-pull-to-refresh/) is a tutorial on how to use it in your application.

Comment: <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
    android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh_listview"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ececec"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

I use it correctly?